# Need to save after QuerySet update?

Tags: python, django, database, orm

I need to updates all the entries in my database that meet a certain condition. I can obtain them by filtering the correspondent model and update them using the `update` method on the obtained QuerySet, but I don't know if I have to execute the `save` method on every object of the QuerySet to save the changes or if the changes are saved to the DB automatically.

Comment: What happened when you tried without saving? What about the [documentation for the `update()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) explain, if you call `QuerySet.update`, that translates to a single `UPDATE` SQL query, so its effects are applied right away. The `update` method doesn't even return a QuerySet anymore, so you can't even iterate over it. It will return the number of affected objects instead.